# What does "Rakanishu" mean?

Tags: diablo-ii

When I'm going through fighting off enemies in Diablo 2, and I hear the little monsters utter a saying, does the saying "Rakanishu" have any meaning in the Diablo games? So far I have only heard it said in #2, is it said in any others?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@deutschZuid is right on.

In Diablo II, Rakanishu is a unique Carver mob that always spawns next to the Cairn Stones in Stony Field.

> Rakanishu is a Super Unique Carver found in the Stony Field next to the Cairn Stones that activate the portal to Tristram during the Search for Cain quest.

[(Diablo Wiki)](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Rakanishu)

It is also said by event mobs in Diablo III. An "Avatar of Rakanishu" makes a cameo in the Dahlgur Oasis and drops a unique named weapon.

> There is a randomized event in the Dalghur Oasis that is tied to Rakanishu in Diablo III as well. Several Fallen members on top of a hill are seen performing a ritual at a stone surrounded by 5 other stones. Upon destruction of the 5 stones, an Avatar of Rakanishu arrives. Killing him prompts the optional objective to destroy the stone he arrived at, before the event is completed. The 5 stones surrounding the center are also a nod to the Cairn Stones from Act I of Diablo II. The title shown when targeting the Avatar of Rakanishu is 'Fallen Demigod'. This is most likely why the Fallen Ones sometimes utter his name as a war cry.

[(Diablo Wiki)](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Rakanishu)

Comment: I can confirm that Rakanishu always appearns within the Cairn Stones.